# Trying to change the color scheme through the css file, but no permission

Tags: 11.10, appearance, css, editing

I have been trying to switch out the orange color scheme in Ubuntu 11.10 through the css files. I know where the files are and what I need to change in them, but every time i try to save it it says that I can not since I don't have permission. Is there a way to get permission?
I am using Bluefish editor fyi.

Answer (score 3):

To put it bluntly, you're doing it wrong.

You need to copy the `GTK` theme into `/home/yourname/.themes/`

Then you should be able to edit it, rename it and then select it in the appearance settings.

*[Related question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54605/how-to-change-overlay-scrollbar-color)*

Answer (score 0):

Try editing as root. The easiest way to do that is in the command line, so start by going to the folder where the files are:

```
user@localhost:~$ cd /path/to/files
```

(don't forget you can press tab to complete long or complex names!)

Then load up your editor of choice. I assume that bluefish loads with 'bluefish' but if not, try tab-completion to find what the name of it is:

```
user@localhost:/path/to/files$ gksu bluefish style.css
```

It will prompt you for your password then, hopefully, run bluefish as superuser with the ability to make changes to the file.

THAT SAID, consider what jrg said, as if you have to go in as superuser to change a user setting, there's probably something you're not quite doing right.